# GenericTypeDefinitionName from IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

**NOTE**: *This question is about a technical aspect, and **NOT** about design decisions. Answering or commenting about a different design does **NOT** answer this question, since I'm only interested in the nature of the technical aspect of this specific question.*

In `C# 6.0` I have this method where I'm passing an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<object> list) { ... }
```

Let's say the caller calls it on an `MyClass[]` array.
What I want is the class name of the generic type definition, I had this implementation of the method:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<object> list)
{
    ...
    var name =
        from abstraction in list.GetType().GetInterfaces()
        where abstraction.IsGenericType
        && abstraction.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
        from genericArgumentType in abstraction.GetGenericArguments()
        select genericArgumentType.Name;
    ...
}
```

Now in this case (inside the body of the method), this correctly returns the name of the class (e.g. a string `"MyClass"`). So I tried to refactor this into an open generic extension method like so:

```
public static string GetGenericTypeDefinitionName<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    var name =
        from abstraction in list.GetType().GetInterfaces()
        where abstraction.IsGenericType
        && abstraction.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
        from genericArgumentType in abstraction.GetGenericArguments()
        select genericArgumentType.Name;

    return name.Single();
}
```

And then call `GetGenericTypeDefinitionName()` from within `MyMethod()` like so:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<object> list)
{
    ...
    var name = list.GetGenericTypeDefinitionName();
    ...
}
```

Which also works, but then I realized: '**Hey! Why not just** `return typeof(T).Name`**?**'

Which turned out it returns the string `"Object"`, while I expected the same result (e.g. `"MyClass"`) as the previous implementation.

Is it even possible to get the expected type? It seems all information is lost when dealing with the open generic type `T`.
Also why am I not getting the expected type? What are the technical details of this particular behavior for `C#`?

Comment: Can you show how exactly you called it so that `typeof(T).Name` returned `"Object"`?

Comment: Are you using generic variance by any chance? an `IEnumerable<SomeType>` can be assigned to an `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: @RenéVogt I've edited the question to show how and where the extension method is called.

Comment: @QuantumHive the example added in the edit is entirely consistent with what I've speculated at in the answer below; if it is *actually* a `List<SomeType>`, then: you're using generic variance

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I've edited my question to show that the original consumer of `MyMethod` passes in an actual array type.

Comment: @QuantumHive for that to work, you'd need it to be `MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)`, and so on and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe will happen if you use generic variance to assign an `IEnumerable<T>` of some reference-type `T` to an `IEnumerable<object>`.

The compiler is going to use **what it knows** to pick the `<T>` at compile-time, which is `object` in this case. If you use reflection, however, you will get the original name - because the **actual object** is unchanged by variance trick.

```
static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> typed = new Foo[0];
    IEnumerable<object> untyped = typed;

    Console.WriteLine(typed.GetByGenerics());     // Foo
    Console.WriteLine(untyped.GetByGenerics());   // Object

    Console.WriteLine(typed.GetByReflection());   // Foo
    Console.WriteLine(untyped.GetByReflection()); // Foo
}
public static string GetByGenerics<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return typeof(T).Name;
}
public static string GetByReflection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    var name =
        from abstraction in list.GetType().GetInterfaces()
        where abstraction.IsGenericType
        && abstraction.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)
        from genericArgumentType in abstraction.GetGenericArguments()
        select genericArgumentType.Name;

    return name.Single();
}
```

This is because you're actually calling

```
Console.WriteLine(GetByGenerics<Foo>(typed));      // Foo
Console.WriteLine(GetByGenerics<Object>(untyped)); // Object
```

Comment: both will write on console actual type?

Comment: @Ehsan I've added the console outputs to the example in the edit

Comment: I think I understand. So because in my question `MyMethod` has a compile time type defined (`IEnumerable<object>`) in it's arguments, the `GetByGenerics` example will never know the original type (`IEnumerable<Foo>`) based on the open generic type `T`, correct? Because this is defined at compile time, and cannot be inferred by the compiler?